# jQuery - onClick check if other div with same class is visible and hide it

Tags: jquery

I have the `Show content` button and need to show a div with the class `tip` when user clicks on it. How can I check if other divs using the same class are visible and if so hide them?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/et7ec25g/4/)**

```
$('.js-help-content').hide();

$('.js-show-help').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.js-help-content').fadeToggle(200);
});
$('.js-help-content').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function(){
     $('.js-help-content').fadeOut(200);
});
```

Comment: You'd have better to provide a more relevant jsFiddle regarding your expected behaviour

Comment: @A.Wolff what do you mean?

Comment: Why would it not be as simple as `$('.tip').on('click', function() { $('.tip:visible').hide(); });`?

Comment: Your jsFiddle has only one element with class `tip`, one 'button' (which isn't a button) and anyway your `.tip` element is visible by default. It really doesn't looks like relevant to your question imho

Comment: @A.Wolff no, there are 2 divs using the class tip. However I am targeting the one using the class js-help-content and once I show that div I want to hide other divs using the class tip if they are visible on the page.

Comment: @brunodd So my bad, i misreaded your HTML markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your button onclick function:

`$('.tip:visible:not(.js-help-content)').hide();`

It has no effect on your `js-help-content` class which you are toggling, and also hides every other visible `tip` class.

Like this:

```
$('.js-show-help').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.tip:visible:not(.js-help-content)').hide();
    $('.js-help-content').fadeToggle(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.tip:visible').not(this).hide();
```

```js
$('.js-help-content').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.tip:visible').not(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="js-show-help">Show content</p>

<div class="located-content tip js-help-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae dolore ad, laboriosam sequi quia doloremque atque ex culpa aperiam ut.</p>
</div>

<div class="tip">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum repudiandae, sequi mollitia inventore provident impedit numquam molestiae culpa dolorem minima odit quod nemo facilis voluptate esse quis voluptatem velit, architecto iusto dolorum praesentium! Vel deserunt quod ad, quas aliquid rerum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Almost there. I tried your solution. It works but I can't hide the red div if I click on 'Show content' button. Any idea?http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/et7ec25g/5/

Comment: What are you requirements?

Comment: Considering where you've placed the line, the `this` must be changed to `.js-help-content`.